# limit epsilon-delta definition vs. continuity

Tags: limits

Based on the following problem from [this source](http://math.uchicago.edu/~vipul/teaching-0910/151/applyingformaldefinitionoflimit.pdf):

$f(x) = \begin{cases}x^2 &, \text{ if } x \text{ rational} \\ x &, \text{ if } x \text{ irrational}\end{cases}$
has $\lim_{x\to 1} f(x) = 1$

and on [this math.stackexchange answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/60978/137540), I suspect that limit does **not** require a "continuous" domain.

But, why the common $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of a limit $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = L$ ($a$ is neither $-\infty$ nor $\infty$) **never** emphasizes that point? For example, my [textbook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0073532320) simply says $x$ without explaining any property about $x$, and therefore, I was wrongfully led to believe that $x$ must come from a "continuous" domain.

I see that Wikipedia's [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%28%CE%B5,_%CE%B4%29-definition_of_limit#Precise_statement) on precise definition of limit explicitly states that $x \in D \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. But, I think it may also wrongfully lead people to believe that limit $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = L$ also works when the domain is so discontinuous like the set $\mathbb{Z}$ of integers and $a$ is neither $-\infty$ nor $\infty$.

Now I am wondering: what is the precise definition of limit $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = L$ ($a$ is neither $-\infty$ nor $\infty$) especially when it comes to being precise about the $x$?

Comment: What do you mean by a "continuous domain"? Continuity is a property of functions, not of sets.

Comment: @learnmore indicates that the formal term is "cluster point". So, what I mean is a domain in the sense of the other math.stackexchange answer where between any two of its elements, there is always another element (e.g., the domain of rational numbers has that property whereas the domain of integer numbers has it not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we define limit we consider $a$ to be a cluster point of the domain.By a cluster point we mean the following:

If $a$ is a cluster point of $A$ then $(a-\delta,a+\delta)\cap A\setminus \{a\}\neq\phi$

So the exact definition of a limit is

Let $\epsilon >0$ be arbitrary.Then $ f$ has $L $ has limit as $x \rightarrow a$ if corresponding to $\epsilon >0 \exists \delta >0 $ such that whenever $x\in  (a-\delta,a+\delta)\cap A\setminus \{a\}, |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ .

Comment: And, do you have any idea as to why such a good definition of cluster point never enters the precise definition of epsilon-delta definition of limit? The wording of the precise limit in Wikipedia indicates that not many people understand the concept of cluster point when dealing with the precise definition of limit.

Comment: Do you really mean $a$ is a cluster point or $a$ is a limit point instead?

Comment: Consult any standard book on real analysis.You will always find defn of cluster point before limit definition